# Get Application Directory in the Installer Class

Tags: .net, installation, custom-action

How can I get the directory that an application is being installed to from within the custom installer class?

What we are trying to solve is the age old problem of *.config files for multiple environments. One idea we were kicking around was having the configs stored on a network share, and the  installer would copy over the correct one. Currently we use the method described on [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/21/tip-trick-automating-dev-qa-staging-and-production-web-config-settings-with-vs-2005.aspx), but we would like the files to be out of dev's hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that `this.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]` will get you the file location of the primary output (c:\program files\Company\MyAssembly.exe). You can always parse out the path from that. It isn't the best solution, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, perhaps you can have the app copy that file when it is first run. The app knows where it's running from.